# Scaling a rails database queue system

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, scalability

I have a widget that users can select as being for sale. 
Other users can tell my app that they want to buy these widgets.
The first widgets sold to the buying users are the ones that has been for sale the longest, so making a queue.

My question is this:

**How do I make an app that tracks a queue at this scale?**

Obviously if you have to order a table of sales that's a million rows long by their sale date, you're going to have a terribly long SQL query, right?

Is this a situation where I should use workers?

Or is there a queue management system for rails that would make this simple?

Comment: A million rows is nothing if you index it correctly...how many "widgets" do you foresee being for sale on your site?

Comment: Also I think you are misinterpreting the use of a "queue" - queues in this sense are used to asynchronously send messages back and forth between decoupled components of your application. What you're referring to is just a way of accessing your data, so you wouldn't need a worker.

Comment: I wouldn't try to preempt a problem that doesn't exist. In your case, convince yourself that the system does not scale to a million requests, and that you do have a million requests, before engineering an optimization. RDBMS systems handle a million record quite well, with right indices.